# Java maven project trying to read file from resources

Tags: java, maven, file, resources, web-inf

I am trying to read an xml file from the resources folder of maven web project, but instead of trying to read it from the source files, it tries to read from jar file generated in the WEB-INF folder, which throws a not found exception. How can I address this issue? Thanks

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("folder_x/file.xml").getFile());
```

Under resources, I have folder_x and in there I have file.xml

If i run:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/folder_x/file.xml").getFile());
```

I get null pointer exception.

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">; 
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>xmltest</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmltest</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
</project>
```

Comment: please post your pom.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xmltest</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmltest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>

Comment: Where lies your resources? Please post the complete path

Comment: src/main/resources/folder_x

Comment: Works for me. Do you have really the semicolons in your pom.xml? If so please remove them. Which mvn goal do you execute? `mvn clean install` works for me.

Comment: You should not try to access a resource via file. You should use a stream like `getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/dolder_x/file.xml")` cause this will later be packaged into a jar file...

Comment: Ok, i agree it will get packaged as a jar. I need to read the xml as a File object though. If i read it in an inputstream the validation i do doesnt work.